# Is "deacceleratingly" a valid word?

Tags: adverbs, is-it-a-word, dictionaries, present-participles

*Deaccelerate* means the same as *decelerate*, though it seems to be a much less common alternative. I did not know this until recently, as I had used this alternative all my life. It just seemed logical to me, *deaccelerate* is *accelerate* with a negative prefix. I came to believe that *deaccelerate* was the "father" of *decelerate*, as *decelerate* seems like a word that derived from the former word due to practicality. I do not know if this is true though. What I do know is that *decelerate* is a lot more used and much more popular than *deaccelerate*, something I am reminded off when my browser constantly puts a red line under the word. Yet, it is listed in many dictionaries, proving that it is indeed a valid word.

So then my question is, why isn't *deacceleratingly* a valid word? Both *deaccelerating* and *deceleratingly* are valid words, but *deacceleratingly* is not listed anywhere and also gets a red line under itself. It just doesn't make sense to me to leave out this piece of the "word's set". Of course, *deaccelerate* is unpopular, so it's safe to assume that *deacceleratingly* is even less used, but does it really take **that** much time to add the word into the dictionaries and Chrome's own browser? I know that this is getting a bit too discussion-like, so I'll return to my core question.

Is *deacceleratingly* a word? Is it simply ignored by all the dictionaries, but still technically a word, or is it a completely invalid and ungrammatical word?

Comment: Do you have a source for "deceleratingly" as a word? [This](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/deceleratingly) implies otherwise. [Similar](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Deaccelerate) for your variant spelling, although [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decelerate%2C+deaccelerate&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecelerate%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeaccelerate%3B%2Cc0) implies a few hits (could be misuse, though). Decelerating is a word.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deceleratingly http://www.yourdictionary.com/deceleratingly https://www.wordnik.com/words/deceleratingly  Please do not cite one dictionary and say that the word doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you asking about *deceleratingly* or *deacceleratingly*? Your comment points to the former but your question refers to the latter. Either way, English is a productive language. The prefix de- and the suffix -ly can be added to many words, with the resulting words not necessarily catalogued in dictionaries.

Comment: I am asking about deacceleratingly. Though my first comment was about deceleratingly, as it was a response to the comment before. The fact that deceleratingly is a word was vital in my question though, as I believe if deceleratingly is a word then deacceleratingly is a word too. This comment got a bit clunky, sorry if it was unclear. @Lawrence

Comment: No problem, your second comment was clear enough. I'm not a linguist - I just speak the language :) - but I suspect that the test for whether something is a proper word is whether there exists a sentence in which that 'word' is meaningful and can be assigned some part of speech. Of broader concern is whether it is readily understandable by whoever you're communicating that word to, taking into account denotation and connotation etc.

Comment: What makes you think it isn't a valid word? It is constructed from productive morphemes and obeys the phonological rules of English. It's meaning is transparent. It may be rare or even never used but it is still a valid word.

Comment: I knew that it obeyed all grammatical rules, but so does "decheesingly", doesn't make it a valid word though. To paint what I mean clearer I guess I'll define "decheesingly". -In a decheesing manner. Decheesing is not a valid word either, yet it obeys all grammatical laws. Decheesing would mean removing cheese from an object of composition. Though, deacceleringly is not nearly as obscure as my example above, it kind of falls into the same conundrum. @JamesRandom

Comment: "Decheesingly" is a perfectly valid and cromulent word. You are able to explain its derivation and meaning. Perhaps you need to define what you mean by "valid word"? Do you mean one that someone else has invented? Or one that has been used more than once? Or often enough to get into one dictionary? Or ... ?

Comment: You make good points. I believed that someone like me wasn't "allowed" to create words like i.e. "decheesingly". Perhaps there is no example of a word obeying all grammatical rules being invalid. Maybe the only words that actually are invalid are those who aren't grammatically correct. If so, "deacceleratingly" is a valid word, just one that isn't listed anywhere, like "decheesingly". Thank you for your enlightening me, @JamesRandom

Comment: Anyone can invent new words. And they don't even have to be formed following the usual rules of morphology or derivation. For example: *Twas brillig, and the slithy toves. Did gyre and gimble in the wabe: All mimsy were the borogoves,. And the mome raths outgrabe.*

Comment: @A.Kvåle, your three references all reference the same wiktionary entry, and a wiki is sometimes an unreliable source. [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com) is a conglomeration of several published dictionaries and as such is somewhat more acceptable. For something to be considered a word, you need one person to say/write and understand it and at least one other person to hear/read and interpret it. A word in a wiki could come from a single person. If you use "deacceleratingly", people will probably understand what you mean but may judge your unusual word choice.

Comment: Regarding _deaccelerate_ vs _decelerate_, both go back to Latin _celerare_ ‘hasten’, from the adverb _celer_ meaning ‘swiftly’ (cf. _celerity_ in English). _Accelerate_ is _ad-_ ‘towards’ + _celerare_ ‘swiftness’, literally ‘going towards hastening’ = speeding up. _Decelerate_, then, substitutes ‘towards’ for ‘away from’: ‘going away from hastening’ = slowing down. _Deaccelerate_ combines them, meaning ‘going away from going towards hastening’, which sort of ends up being the same thing, but is semantically much more complex.

Comment: I’m confused by all of this as the word accelerate is the rate of change in velocity. When one slows from a higher velocity to a lower velocity you accelerate with a negative quantity. From the scientific standpoint acceleration is a vector quantity and is made of two numbers, magnitude and direction. If one changes direction without changing speed, you have accelerated. If you reverse direction without changing speed, you have accelerated. Speed is a scalar quantity and as such has no direction unlike velocity which is a vector quantity. Decelerate is a word that should never be used as it me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, you can use words *deaccelerate* or *deacceleratingly*.

You won't find it in standard dictionaries like [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deaccelerate) or [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/search?filter=dictionary&query=deaccelerate). But you can certainly use them.

But, yes, it is true, I seldom came across the words called "**de**accelerate" or “**de**acceleratingly" in any of the reference books while in my under-graduation in physics.

Also, **de**accelerate is not a mother of *decelerate*. Actually, the verb [**decelerate**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/decelerate)(1899) is a backformation of the noun [**deceleration**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/deceleration?ref=etymonline_crossreference) (1894).

You can use prefix [***de-***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/de_2) to make *combining forms* e.g. **de**accelerate or **de**acceleratingly:

> 1. **de-** is added to a verb in order to change the meaning of the verb to its opposite.
> 2. **de-** is added to a noun in order to make it a verb referring to the removal of the thing described by the noun.

So, yes you can use deaccelerate or deacceleratingly, it is not grammatically wrong.

Comment: The fact that "deaccelerate" is uncommon and rarely used was not new to me, as I mentioned in my question. That you didn't come across it either does not really answer my question as it only tells me your subjective experience of the word, and not a source saying whether the word is proper English or not.

Comment: @A.Kvåle you are not wrong. It is rarely used. I have edited further :)

Comment: Thank you, your edit improved much. Sorry if I was a bit douchey in my comment.  Good that you added de-, as I didn't know a prefix could have an hyphen after it.

Comment: I think the second year should be 1899, not 1988, based on your reasoning and the link.

Comment: @jejorda2 Oh! the typo. Thanks! edited :)

Answer (score 1):

The OP’s, very understandable, mistake was to think of *accelerate* as the ‘father’ of the word in question. This led the OP to add *de-* to it, analogously to the way in which we, for example, add *de-* to *alcoholise* to  get *dealcoholise*, the verb for the opposite action. It is, however, better to think of *decelerate* and *accelerate* as siblings. The *a-* at the beginning of *accelerate* is itself a prefix; both words are thus formed by adding different prefixes to the common root. Their ultimate ancestor is the Latin word *celer*, meaning fast, swift, rapid; to accelerate is thus to make something fast, to decelerate is to make it the opposite of fast, that is slow. While, there is no word *celerate* in English, there is *celerity* which belongs to the same family, and makes the root more clearly visible. The relationship between *accelerate* and *decelerate* is analogous to that between *appreciate* and *depreciate* (note that we do not say *deappreciate*), not to that between *alcoholise* and *dealcoholise*.

Another way to think of it is this. What does the action of decelerating take away? It does not just take away acceleration: if one accelerates, and then merely takes away the acceleration, the result is that the motion continues at the speed, possibly very high, which was reached by the acceleration. The action of decelerating takes away the speed, velocity, celerity. That’s why the word is *decelerate* rather than *deaccelerate*.

Using the word *deaccelerate* is thus not merely a stylistic faux pas that would annoy some stuffy linguistic prescriptivists, but is otherwise harmless. It can create confusion, because when we hear it, we cannot be sure whether it is used as a variant of *decelerate*, or to mean removing the accelaration (but possibly continuing at high speed), which is what it would mean, according to the principles that generally govern the prefix *de-*.

Comment: Good point, the ending of acceleration and continuing to move at the final speed could well be called deaccelerating. However the ending of deceleration and continuing to move at the final speed would, presumably, be dedecelerating.